# Apply formatting to a range using array loop - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Using VBA i make to:

- Set two ranges
- Create an array of all ranges names
- Loop the array in order to apply formatting to each range in the array

BUT on line `.Interior.Color = vbRed`

i receive the below error:

> Run-time error '424': Object required

**Code**

```
Sub test()

    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
    Dim strRanges As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Set rng1 = Sheet1.Range("A1:D1")
    Set rng2 = Sheet2.Range("C5:H5")

    strRanges = Split("rng1,rng2", ",")

    For i = LBound(strRanges) To UBound(strRanges)
        With strRanges(i)
            .Interior.Color = vbRed
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

i have already use:

`With Range(strRanges(i))`

instead of:

`With strRanges(i)`

without any luck!

Any help will appreciate.

Comment: Does `strRanges` contain any ranges?

Comment: No, is just an array containing all ranges name.

Comment: Change `strRanges = Split("rng1,rng2", ",")` in `strRanges = Split(rng1.Address & "," & rng2.Address, ",")`  and use `With Range(strRanges(i))`. You cannot build an object range from a string (directly)...

Comment: Agree with @FaneDuru with one notice - as far as you are using ranges on different sheets it would work properly with `strRanges = Split(rng1.Address(External:=True) & "," & rng2.Address(External:=True), ",")` line instead. Otherwise, you will paint ranges on active sheet only.

Comment: Correct. Or use a workaround in the loop: `if i = 0 then ... With Sheet1.Range(strRanges(i)) ... Else ... Sheet2.Range(strRanges(i))`... But your solution is obviously more elegant.

Comment: Haha have never thought about using a variable as a variable. I'd love to play around with this myself! What an elegant way. Anyway, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29176126/excel-2010-vba-use-value-of-variable-as-another-variable this seems like what you want? Only downtime I see is that you need to add a reference.

Comment: You could just use `Array` here instead of `Split`.

Comment: @BigBen i use `strRanges = Array("rng1", "rng2")`  but i receive the same error. Could you please post the answer?

Comment: `Array(rng1, rng2)` - add the range objects to the array.

Comment: I am afraid that Union is not possible for ranges in different sheets...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can do this in just one line if the ranges are *in the same worksheet*

   ```
   Sheet1.Range("A1:D1,C5:H5").Interior.Color = vbRed
   ```
2. You can use union if the ranges are *in the same worksheet*

   ```
   Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
   Set rng1 = Sheet1.Range("A1:D1")
   Set rng2 = Sheet1.Range("C5:H5")
   Union(rng1, rng2).Interior.Color = vbRed
   ```
3. You can use real arrays for your ranges if they *are in different worksheets*

   ```
   Sub test()    
       Dim rng(1 To 2) As Range
       Set rng(1) = Sheet1.Range("A1:D1")
       Set rng(2) = Sheet2.Range("C5:H5")

       Dim i As Long
       For i = LBound(rng) To UBound(rng)
           With rng(i)
               .Interior.Color = vbRed
           End With
       Next i    
   End Sub
   ```
4. If you don't have numbered range variable names then you can use another array:

   ```
   Sub test()    
       Dim rngABC As Range, rngXYZ As Range
       Set rngABC = Sheet1.Range("A1:D1")
       Set rngXYZ = Sheet1.Range("C5:H5")

       Dim ArrRng() As Variant
       ArrRng = Array(rngABC, rngXYZ)

       Dim rng As Variant
       For Each rng In ArrRng
           rng.Interior.Color = vbRed
       Next rng     
   End Sub
   ```

Note that if you think you have to use numbered variable names like

```
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
```

this always is a clear sign for using an array instead:

```
Dim rng(1 To 2) As Range
```

numbered variable names are a bad practice. Always choose meaningful names.

Comment: My guess is that OP is working with a dynamically created `String` of all the ranges in question... which is a bad idea in the first place... but could be wrong. In any case this is the right approach.

Comment: @BigBen: Ups... Again did not read with enough attention til the end... I will delete mai comment.

Comment: @BigBen: Or, maybe I did not refresh my page and that's why i did not see something maybe not existing... (Good excuse :))...

Comment: @BigBen i have create an array with all my ranges and loop the ranges in the array in order to apply some formatting. Thanks for you answer. it s works. Could you please share it as an answer in order to vote?

Comment: @Error1004 - PEH's answer works as it uses an array.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ thanks for your time. No, i dont use number as a variable names in my code. the number names were for the example.

Comment: @Error1004 I added number 4 just to make the answer complete.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ thanks for tha addition. I loop array using Lbound and Ubound and i get the same answer. Thanks for your time. Is it a good idea to post my answer too?